# Inconsistencies in changing content in txt files

Tags: python, file-io

I have encountered inconsistent issues with python file-io.

```
def update_links(dir_name):
    iterator = 1
    with open('filename.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        data = file.read()
        for match in re.findall('\<img.*\/\>', data):
            data = data.replace('media/image' + str(iterator) + '.jpg',
            dir_name + '/' + str(iterator) + '.png')
            iterator += 1
        file.seek(0)
        file.truncate()
        file.write(data)
```

So what I am trying to do is update these automatically generated links to how they actually appear in where the document is referencing them. There is no issue in the regex finding all the matches I need, I have tested this, but it does not replace the content in some documents I've tested this on. I've noticed that in some larger documents, it will convert either some of the links, or none of them at all. I have tried using time.sleep() between iterations but it makes no difference. I am unsure what the issue could be, but any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. What confuses me most is that it works perfectly on some files.

Comment: It looks like you don't use `match` in your `replace` call? Do you mean `match` instead of `iterator` in your replace argument? Also `dir_name` isn't used? That aside, it feels most likely that the replace is the problem in some way shape or form.

Comment: @daddydan it looks like the only purpose of the regular expression is to count the number of `<img>` tags in the file.

Comment: I would guess that the problem is the assumption that the form of all the images will be like `media/image1.jpg`.  Remember that `replace` is case sensitive.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yeah I do see what you mean about regex now. I have tried creating a variable inside the the loop which I assign to the match, use replace for the form I would like in the match for the new variable, and replace text that way, however, I still have the same issue of this code inconsistently working on other files. Also every file I am working with does have that exact format as they are automatically generated.

Comment: Without an example file that this fails on I don't think you're going to get any help.